# WSDL validator?

Tags: web-services, wsdl

Is there any online service available to validate Web Service WSDL file?

Comment: Also check out https://www.wsdl-analyzer.com/

Comment: @MattH : It is the best service for this purpose.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Eclipse, just have your WSDL in a .wsdl file, eclipse will validate it automatically.

From the [Doc](http://wiki.eclipse.org/WSDL_Validator)

> The WSDL validator handles validation
>   according to the 4 step process
>   defined above. Steps 1 and 2 are both
>   delegated to Apache Xerces (and XML
>   parser). Step 3 is handled by the WSDL
>   validator and any extension namespace
>   validators (more on extensions below).
>   Step 4 is handled by any declared
>   custom validators (more on this below
>   as well). Each step must pass in order
>   for the next step to run.

Comment: Visual Studio as well (in 2008 and later, at least, not sure about previous versions).

Answer (score 1):

You can try using one of their tools: http://www.ws-i.org/deliverables/workinggroup.aspx?wg=testingtools

These will check both WSDL validity and [Basic Profile 1.1](http://www.ws-i.org/Profiles/BasicProfile-1.1-2004-08-24.html) compliance.

Comment: Hi, the link is borken now.

Comment: Not working, does not open

Comment: http://www.ws-i.org/deliverables/testingtools.html seems to be the new link

Answer (score 1):

If you would to validate WSDL programatically then you use WSDL Validator out of eclipse. http://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_the_WSDL_Validator_Outside_of_Eclipse should help or try this tool Graphical WSDL 1.1/2.0 editor.

Answer (score -1):

You can try out wsdl validator http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB451/WSDL+Validator

Comment: Not working, does not open

Answer (score -2):

you might want to look at the online version of [xsv](http://www.w3.org/2001/03/webdata/xsv)

Comment: The XML Schema Validator service has been Discontinued.