# How to create a soap client without WSDL

Tags: c#, web-services, header, token, ws-security

i need to visit a secure web service,
every request in the header need to carry a token.

i know the endpoint to the web service,
i also know how to create the token.

but i cannot see the WSDL for the webservice.

is there a way in C#, to create a soap client, without the WSDL file.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278037/soap-client-in-c-without-access-to-a-wsdl-file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have verified that this code, which uses the [HttpWebRequest class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx), works:

```
// Takes an input of the SOAP service URL (url) and the XML to be sent to the
// service (xml).  
public void PostXml(string url, string xml) 
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
    request.ContentType = "text/xml";

    using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
       requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }

    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            string message = String.Format("POST failed with HTTP {0}", 
                                           response.StatusCode);
            throw new ApplicationException(message);
        }
    }
}
```

You will need to create the proper SOAP envelope and pass that in as the "xml" variable.  It takes some reading.  I found this [SOAP Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/soap/default.asp) to be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

A SOAP client is simply an HTTP client with more stuff in it. See the [HttpWebRequest class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx). You'll then have to create your own SOAP message, perhaps using XML Serialization.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own service, expose it to have a WSDL and then generate the client from that... kind of the long way.

Answer (score 0):

Can you ask the developers of the web service to send you the WSDL and XSD file(s) by email? If so, you can dump the files in a folder and then add a Service Reference using the WSDL on your hard disk.