# How to check if a web service response XML is compliant with its WSDL? (I need an offline tool to check the xml files)

Tags: wsdl

I'm calling a web service, and I'm suspecting its response is not according to its specification. I'm not a WSL specification expert, so I'd like to ask if someone knows a tool that can be used to perform a validation between a WSDL file and a sample XML response. Does anyone know a tool that can validate if a sample XML response is according to WSDL specification?

Also, if you know a tool which I can provide the WSDL file and it generates a sample XML response it would work too.

Thanks,

Comment: Duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152023/wsdl-validator

Comment: Actually I need an offline tool for performing that validation, since I cannot send the WSDL file to a public website. Can you reopen the question?

Comment: @CarlosLoth It isn't closed, just has 1 vote to close. Needs 5

Comment: *not* a duplicate - the other question is about validating a wsdl, but this is about validating a web service response.

Answer (score 1):

SOAP UI is the perfect tool for this. Create a Test Case and add 'schema compliance' assertion. This would validate whether the SOAP response is compliant with the WSDL specification or not.

Detailed instruction can be found here: https://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/validating-soap-services.html

Thanks,
Sandeep